# ng-class - Error: Token '-' is at column {2}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I have a problem with ng-class. If the role has admin privileges, it is to add a class-disabled state. Now occurs error

html:

```
<label class="toggle modal-label-box" ng-class="{state-disabled: checkCanModify()}">
   <input type="radio" name="radio-toggle" ng-model="role" value="guest">
   <i data-swchon-text="ON" data-swchoff-text="OFF"></i>No role
</label>
```

js:

```
$scope.checkCanModify = function() {
    return ($scope.role == "admin" ? true : false);
};
```

error:

```
Syntax Error: Token '-' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

How i can this fixed ?
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put quotes around the class:

```
"{'state-disabled': checkCanModify()}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ngClass` directive when you use object notation, like with any normal javascript object, property name mush be a valid identifier. If it's not, you have to wrap it in quotes:

```
ng-class="{'state-disabled': checkCanModify()}"
```